# Two .htaccess files doesn't work together

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two htaccess files and one of them located in root directory and other one in **gifts/** directory.

**Root** .htaccess contains:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /gifts/
RewriteRule gifts/([A-Za-z0-9]+(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]+)*)$ gifts/catalog.php?catalog=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /gifts/
RewriteRule gifts/([A-Za-z0-9]+(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]+)*)/([0-9]+)$ gifts/catalog.php?catalog=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
```

**Gifts/** .htaccess contains:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gifts.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]+)*)$ /catalog.php?catalog=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gifts.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]+)*)/([0-9]+)$ /catalog.php?catalog=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
```

When I go to the following URL:

> http://gifts.example.com/jeans

It works, but the following URL doesn't work

> http://example.com/gifts/jeans

Not Found error occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `gifts/.htaccess` as:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /gifts/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ catalog.php?catalog=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ catalog.php?catalog=$1&page=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: It works for http://example.com/gifts/jeans now, but not for http://gifts.example.com/jeans

Comment: This rule has nothing to do with `gifts.example.com/jeans` since it is inside `/gifts/` directory